# Cambiar de GET a POST

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

poseo el siguiente codigo JS

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.add-to-cart').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).closest('.col').find('#product-id').text();
    var name = $(this).closest('.col').find('#product-name').text();
    var quantity = $(this).closest('.btn-group').find('#quantity').val();

    window.location.href = "../agregar.php?id=" + id + "&name=" + name + "&quantity=" + quantity;
    });

    $('.update-quantity').click(function(){
        var id = $(this).closest('tr').find('.product-id').text();
        var name = $(this).closest('tr').find('.product-name').text();
        var quantity = $(this).closest('tr').find('input').val();
        window.location.href = "../actualizar.php?id=" + id + "&name=" + name + "&quantity=" + quantity;
    });
});
</script>
```

Mi consulta en concreto es:

Asi como tengo el codigo sera posible cambiar el metodo de envio de GET a POST asi como esta funciona pero cada vez que se agrega un item o se actualiza este recarga toda la web y es lo que me gustaria evitar.

Comment: sea por GET o por POST seguirá pasando lo mismo... te has planteado el saber por que recarga toda la web?

Comment: Utiliza ajax y evita que se recarga la web con un `e.prevendDefault()`, `e` es el evento

Comment: Si se recarga toda para refrescar los datos mostrados, pero sera posible 1- enviar los datos via POST y luego via ajax realizar la recarga de solo los div de la pag sin tener que recargar toda la web

Comment: Otra solucion a mi inconveniente seria evitar que al agregar o actualizar algun componente la web se cargue de nuevo no tengo problemas con ello pero que quede mostrando el mismo componente en donde el usuario estaba.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

utiliza AJAX en vez de `window.location`

suponiendo que tienes las variables:

```
var variable1 = 'Hola';
var variable2 = 'Mundo';
```

**POST**

```
$.post('../actualizar.php',{ variable1, variable2},function(respuesta,status){
   //Aquí trabajas tu respuesta
})
```

o por GET prácticamente igual

**GET**

```
$.get('../actualizar.php',{ variable1, variable2},function(respuesta,status){
   //Aquí trabajas tu respuesta
})
```

el primer parámetro que recibe es la URL a donde haces la petición, el segundo es un objeto con las variables que enviaras, y el tercer parámetro es una función anónima la cual recibe otros dos parámetros, el primero es la respuesta de tu petición y el segundo es el status

dentro de la función anónima trabajaras lo que quieres hacer cuando la petición termine

hay que señalar que existen otras formas que son aun más elaboradas donde puedes controlar aun más detalles, pero para que te introduzcas en este tema creo que es más que suficiente.